# Having problems in overriding the default transition

Tags: android

For some reason I cannot get the overridePendingTransition() to work.  I have tried all method call orders, but still get the default transition.  Am I missing something simple?

```
// in onCreate()
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() { loadNextActivity(); }
}, DURATION);


public void loadNextActivity() {
    startActivity( new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I just got it to work using...

    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 1);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

Note that I did not call finish()...
Are you running in the UI thread?

I am running API level 9

Comment: I think it might be a threading issue.  I have updated the code to show where the loadNextActivity() method is being called.  Is this not within the main UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

no main/minor UI thread. There is only one single thread for UI.

Running in UI thread it should work, regardless of whether finish() is called or not, for startActivity as well as startActivityForResult